# How can I move the position of my Jcomponent after I click a button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jcomponent

So I want to change the position of an image which I implemented as a JComponent after I click the corresponding button, however, it does not do anything when getting clicked.

I think the problem may lay inside my paintComponent method, since I want the image to be drawn in the center of my panel in the beginning.

The panel itself has a GridBagLayout, although I think that anchoring it in the center would not help either, since I want to move the image whenever the button is clicked and only want it to show up in the center of the panel when I open the frame...

For this button in particular I want my JComponent/image to move 50 pixels to the right.

Anyway here's what I did:

```
@Override 
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int x = (this.getWidth() - img.getWidth(null))/2;
    int y = (this.getHeight() - img.getHeight(null))/2;
    
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    img.repaint(img.getX()+50, img.getY(), img.getHeight(), img.getWidth());
}
```

Comment: Save the x and y location (give them more descriptive names) of the image in an application model.  Your `paintComponent` method just draws the image.  Your `actionPerformed` method shifts the x location and calls the `repaint` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your paintComponent method always uses the same values for `x` and `y`, so it should come as no surprise that the image doesn’t move.

`x` and `y` are *state* that needs to be remembered.  This is done by defining instance fields:

```
private int x;
private int y;
```

You can’t initialize them at construction time, because a component has a width and height of zero when it’s created (usually).  Fortunately, there is a method which tells you when a component has been given a width and height;  that method is [addNotify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#addNotify()), which you can and should override:

```
@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();

    x = (this.getWidth() - img.getWidth(this)) / 2;
    y = (this.getHeight() - img.getHeight(this)) / 2; 
}
```

Notice that you should pass `this` (your component instance) to any method which expects an ImageObserver argument, rather than null.

Now paintComponent doesn’t need to do any calculation.  It just paints the image at whatever `x` and `y` happen to be:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
}
```

And now that your coordinates are instance fields, you can change them directly:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    x += 50;
    repaint();
}
```